# Specifying the number of clusters in nearest neighbor clustering

Tags: r, clustering, k-nearest-neighbour, distance

I've got a distance matrix between examples. I want to cluster them into *m* clusters with a nearest neighbor algorithm which works like this:

```
1. Set i = 1 and k = 1. Assign example x_1 to cluster C_1.
2. Set i = i + 1. Find nearest neighbour of x_i
   among the patterns already assigned to clusters.
   Let d_n  denote the distance from x_i to its nearest neighbour.
   Suppose the nearest neighbour is in cluster n.
3. If d_n less than or equal to t then assign x_i to C_n where t is the 
   threshold specified by the user. Otherwise set k = k+1 and assign x_i  to a      
   new cluster C_k.
```

How could I adapt this algorithm so I could specify how many clusters I want?

Is anybody aware of an existing R implementation of nearest neighbour clustering?

Comment: In this algorithm you cannot specify the number of clusters, you can change them varying parameter 't'. For R implementations just Google it, there is at least one.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: In 3. I think you mean "less than equal" instead of "greater than or equal", do you ?

Comment: It is not a homework. Oops, it was a mistake, I mean "less than equal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Dmitry Laptev* already said correctly, the threshold t is determining the number of clusters indirectly. Using your algorithm there is no way to determine the number of clusters beforehand while still producing meaningful results.

As a more convenient bottom-up agglomerative nearest neighbor clustering approach you may want to take a look at [Single Linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_linkage), which works in a comparable (albeit certainly not equivalent) way. Single Linkage is implemented in R in [hclust in the package stats](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/hclust.html)

If you liked this approach, you should also take a look at the other linkage algorithms, especially [Ward's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_chain_algorithm#Ward.27s_method), which tends to deliver better results.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into single linkage hierarhical clustering and it is somehow similar to NN method.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search produces [k-Nearest Neighbour Classification](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/class/html/knn.html) and [knn (weighted k-nearest neighbors](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/index.html)

Comment: I think these two are not meant for clustering (they don't work with distance matrix).

Comment: @genesiss the first link not, but the second one. From the description of the method specClust it uses [spectral clustering](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5b0%5d.pdf), but yes, a precomputed distance matrix cannot be supplied as far as I see.

Comment: Michael, for finding R solutions use http://www.rseek.org instead of Google.  One of the first hits when searching on "cluster" takes you to the [Cluster task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) listing approximately 100(!) packages.